# lose content when change orientation in my list view and in forms android

Tags: android-listview, android-custom-view, android-listfragment, android-orientation, orientation-changes

okay guys, i know that have couple topics with the same purpose, but i'm new on android, and the topics that i found just created more mess in my mind, so thats why i'm here;

I got an app with 5 Activitys(fragments) 2 are list views, and 3 are forms, i'm populating my list views with the content from 2 of my forms;

And the problem is when i change my orientantion i loose everything as everybody knows, but i don't know what and where i need to set some configurations that i found in my research  for example: i saw a lot examples implementing this:

`<activity
  android:name="com.abc.src.MainActivity"
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
 />`

as a solution but many others said that this is not enough, and after this i need to implements one method ex:

`@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            // set visibility visible of Layout in which your list fragment resides 
        }else if(newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            // set visibility gone of Layout in which your list fragment resides
        }
    }`

And the last one, which one makes more sense to me, but i don't know exaclty how and where to implement is:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
savedInstanceState.putString("MyText", edtMyText.getText().toString());
}
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyText");
        edtMyText.setText(myString);
}
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
@Override 
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
???(what and where i need to set) ???
}
```

This last one makes more sense to me in my forms case, that i can get the values of my sppiners and editTexts and save them into a string, but i can't figure out how can i save the items of my list views with this example,

the question is, i understand the purpose of the methods above, but i don't know where i need to implement,

i'm following the MVC pattern, so i guess i need to insert these methods in my view classes right ??

And all my activites is just calling my fragments so i need to set the StateChange methods, in my fragments class or my Activities classes ?

Any helps or solutions will be appreciate, so if you guys need i can update my post with my class code... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not override any of the config changes. Android will handle it for you, especially when it comes to `Views`. Only under the most specific (not common) edge cases should you be overriding config changes.  Remove everything you posted.  You'll find that all `Views` will be recreated accordingly, to include the text in `EditText` widgets.  If not, then your problem lies else where.